# How to generate .sas in SAS data Integration Studio

Tags: linux, sas

Since i want to schedule a job in SAS-DIS. i tried the process using sas management console,but an error is popping up saying scheluing server not found. and  scheduling server is an extra package that has to be purchased.

and because of that i need running on crontab on linux.

Do i need to export my job in SAS Data Integration Studio into format .sas or i can execute using .spk file format ?

if yes, i need to generate into .sas format . Please tell me how to generate that format. since i can't convert it ? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This question is better asked at SAS Communities: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/bd-p/data_management. SAS Tech Support is available as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ´*.pkg ´ file contains much more information than your SAS code. It also contians information on the transformation and option you used as well as the graphical layout of your job.

A simple way to grab your SAS code is to open the properties of your job and select the tab with the code. However, that is not the way you should do it to schedule your job.

What you should do, is to [create a "Deployed Job" object from your job](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/bicdc/9.4/scheduleug/n1h05ens8bwkz7n18s3b2ad8yawa.htm). This has the advantage that your successor, or you when you come back to the project in a year, kan find out where you deployed the code today.